# Why my thread is executed before start and skip the while isAlive?

Tags: python, multithreading

So i'm writing a program to upload certain file in a certain sftp server. Looking for implement a waiting animation while the file is loading i wrote this

```
def uploadFile(file):
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+f'Uploading \n')
    # sftp actions
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+f'Uploaded\n')

def uploadList(list)
    for files in list:
    upload = threading.Thread(name='process', target=uploadFile(file))
    upload.start()
    while upload.isAlive:
        animated_loading()
```

however, when i run the script the program execute the function uploadFile before the start command and consequently it does not run animated_loading. Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why pass `file` to `uploadFile`? Why use `sys.stdout.write` and not `print`? Are you calling any functions at the end, your provided code isn't complete and has some errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *call* to the uploadFile(...) function:

```
uploadFile(file)
```

---

This is your main thread *calling* `uploadFile(file)`, and then creating a new thread, using the return value from the `uploadFile(file)` call as the `target` of the thread.

```
threading.Thread(name='process', target=uploadFile(file))
```

That is to say, using `None` as the `target` because `uploadFile(...)` does not return any value.

---

You probably wanted to do this instead:

```
threading.Thread(name='process', target=uploadFile, args=(file))
```

That will create a new thread whose `target` is the `uploadFile` function. The new thread will call `uploadFile` and pass it the given `args` after the thread is `start()`ed.